# How to update data without ngFor using angular 5

Tags: angular, firebase, angular5, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in firestore.
I want to change in collection ***proyecto.descripcion*** when i press "Update" button.But i can't understand how to realise this without **ngFor"* method

Сode is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcgq2f

Comment: Use Reactive Form or Template driven Form https://angular.io/guide/forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just add a template reference variable to the input field and a click event to the button and then call a update Method on click.

So something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <form>  
      <div>           
        <input
           #newDescription
           type="text" name="Description"
           placeholder="Here new description"
        >
       </div>  
       <div>
          <input 
            type="submit"
            (click)="updateDescription(newDescription.value)"
            value="Update">
       </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

CLASS

```
updateDescription(description: string) {
   this.service.updateDescription(param.id, description);
}
```

SERVICE

```
updateDescription(id: string, description: string){
    // http update here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have `[ngModel]` on your input field, and on click to sate that value to `proyecto.description` value from the list I believe. Set the start value to ngModel value

Comment: Yeap, but i can't return `proyecto.description` from `proyectoSeleccionado` (in my case)